# Where does questions about fixing source to compile belong?

Tags: discussion, scope

I see a lot of compile questions on Server Fault. In my case I want to ask a question about fixing [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663214) in libxml2 so I can get libxml2 to compile with icu support.

So where does patching related questions belong, Server Fault or Stack Overflow?

I'm thinking Stack Overflow, but I'm trying to compile this on a server, so I need confirmation on where to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I think I misunderstood your question originally.

If you're trying to compile and install a package from source, and it's not working, **and you want to edit / path the source to fix this** (I just noticed it looks like *you* submitted the linked bug report) then by all means, Stack Overflow is the place to ask, because you're *rewriting portions of the code* (programming)

Otherwise, see my original answer:

---

If it's *your code which doesn't compile*, or it's a library / API / SDK / whatever you're *using in your code*, I would suggest StackOverflow.

If it's *a software package you're trying to install from source on a *nix system*, I would recommend [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

If it's *a software package you're trying to install from source on a windows system*, ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

If it's *a software package you're trying to install from source on Mac OS X*, ask on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

**Questions about your personal workstation or personal server are off-topic on ServerFault**. Ony ask on ServerFault if this is for a professional server.

Comment: The compilation problem happens on my development server and production server. The issue is --with-icu doesn't work with a custom --prefix.

Comment: I would try Unix & Linux first. You're very likely to get migrated off ServerFault for being offtopic...

Comment: From SF's FAQ: Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity

Comment: hang on, I just reread your question. I may have misunderstood... edited!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll wait a little while for other input here just in case. But you're likely correct, and I'm sure others would agree. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. And good luck, it doesn't sound like you're in a fun situation! =b

Comment: Just saw your edit. So looks like I'm between Unix & Linux and Stack Overflow. And you're right, I do want to modify the package source to fix this. I'll see what others say just to make sure. I'll probably end up linking this to my question where I end up asking it. Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: U&L is viable, but SO is likely better. If the question was "how do I configure this server farm to compile open source code" that would be about the only time this would be on-target for SF. Otherwise if it's "what's the process to build this code for my box" then that would be a better target on SU or U&L.

Comment: I would still say StackOverflow. If the question is "How do I fix *this code*" then it's on-topic for Stack Overflow. If it's "What am *I doing wrong* that causes this code to not work" then Unix & Linux.

Comment: Question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987779/how-do-i-patch-libxml2-so-it-will-compile-with-icu-support-when-using-a-prefix